# How to make fake NDK crashes in Android in order to test Crashlytics integration?

Tags: android, android-ndk, crashlytics, crash-reports

I follow [Get Android NDK crash reports](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/ndk-reports#kotlin+ktx) in order to integrating NDK Crashlytics report.

However, I don't know how to generate a fake NDK crash to test the integration. Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
int* foo = (int*)-1;
printf("%d\n", *foo);
return *foo;
```

[recommendation from firebase support]

you can also just call __android_log_assert(0, "tag", "message")